# Add one more option to android messages long press context menu

Tags: android, message

I wanted to write an app which can store some messages. Currently by doing long press on android messages some options (like "forward message", "delete message" etc) are arrived. I would like to add one more option to this (for example "store this message").

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: would you clarify your question.?

Comment: Currently in android phones, by doing long press on any message in "Test messages" a context menu will be opened with options "Open message", "Delete message" etc. I wanted to add one more option to that context menu.

Comment: What messages are you referring to? Are you talking about the built-in texting app? Or some other app?

Comment: ah okay, what would you prefer [CAB](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html) or [ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html)?

Comment: try below code it runs definitely

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i am referring to the messages that come in built-in texting app.

Comment: @VijayBarbhaya in the below code how does that relate to Messaging? I need to add an extra option to the existing context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
ListView nameList;    
nameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
nameList.setLongClickable(true);
registerForContextMenu(nameList);

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {   
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete / Miss Call Contact");
    menu.add(menu.NONE,1,menu.NONE,"Delete");
    menu.add(menu.NONE,2,menu.NONE,"call");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
  final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
  position = (int)info.id;          
  switch(item.getItemId()) {        
    case DELETE:
       // do something
    case MISSCALL:
       // do something
  }
  return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```